# SQL query convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g and I have three tables whose structure are as follows

```
  Main_id   Sub_id  col1   col2 
   123       123     blah   blah
```

Main_id to Sub_id is a one to one mapping

and in another table I have

```
 id  sub_id type   
  1  123    a
  2  123    b
```

In this table, a sub_id can contain more than one type and

on the third table, I have each type with an address similar to this

```
   Type     Name    address state city zip
    a        x1        a1    s1    c1  z1
    b        x2        a2    s2    c2  z2
```

I can probably have a maximum of three types a/b/c for any main_id/sub_id.

My question is can I achieve an end result with the following columns like this using pivot/case statements. I basically need a query with just one row given a parameter of sub_id/main_id.

```
Main_id   Sub_id   a_name a_address a_state a_city a_zip b_name b_address b_city b_zip....c_zip
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Oracle SQL - Convert N rows' column values to N columns in 1 row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319997/oracle-sql-convert-n-rows-column-values-to-n-columns-in-1-row)